# 2d array to 3d image matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2-d array whose shape is (10000,16) or you can use (x^2, y). The first two columns of this matrix are the x-axes and y-axes which are (:,0) and (:,1). I want to transform this array to this shape (100,100,14) based on the x and y. How should I do this?
for example, the 2-d array looks like this:

```
x      y    value1  value2  ...  value14
-4.95 -4.95 1.1     1.2          ...
-4.85 -4.95 3.2     -1.2         ...
...   ...   ...     ...
4.95  4.95  2.1     1.7          ...
```

I want to transform to a 3-d array, the array should be based on x and y axis. I mean, the shape should be like (100,100,14). The matrix should be arranged liek a graph.

Right now, I not sure is np.reshape work or not since I am not sure the sequence of reshaping. Is there any way convenient to do this task.

Comment: [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

Comment: Another solution could be to use [`griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) to re-interpolate the data on a trusted grid?